# MySQL: how to get the list of fields in a table using ODBC

Tags: mysql, odbc

I am connecting to a MySQL DB trough a terminal who only have a program with an ODBC connection to a MySQL DB. I can put querys in the program, but not access MySQL directly.

I there a way to query the DB to obtain the list of fields in a table other than

```
select * from table
```

??

(don't know why but the select returns a error)

Comment: Why do you always mark your questions as communitiy wiki? That's a functionality for polls, e.g.

Comment: I was trying to go "incognito" but I guess I didn't make it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
describe *tablename*
```

Comment: This time don't work: error: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: Sebastian: please correct the answer so I can mark it as answered

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  COLUMN_NAME
FROM
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
  TABLE_NAME       = 'MyTable'
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SchemaName'  /* added upon Bill Karwin's comment (thanks) */
```

More info on INFORMATION_SCHEMA is [in the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/columns-table.html).

Comment: Yes, but you should also restrict the query to the desired schema.

Answer (score 1):

This works on most databases:

select * from table where 1=0

You get no data in the result set but you do get the column metadata.

Comment: You are right, because the error that I mention in the question was in a invalid character in a field.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM Tablename
```

lists the fields in a table and their properties (data type, whether null values are allowed, whether the field is a primary key, the default value if one has been set, etc.)